# Sharepoint 2013-stored/created Office documents not opening in 2010 client

Tags: 2013, office-integration, internet-explorer

**SYMPTOM**

Created new Word and Excel docs in a SharePoint 2013 Online library. When I attempt to "Edit in Excel" from IE9 to open the file in my Excel 2010 desktop client, I only get a "The webpage cannot be displayed" message with the following in the address bar:

```
ms-excel:ofv|u|https://xyz.sharepoint.com/Shared Documents/xyz.xlsx
```

Analogous results are obtained when attempting to open the Word doc in the Word 2010 Win7 client:

```
ms-word:ofe|u|https://xyz.sharepoint.com/Shared Documents/xyz.docx
```

**THE SYMPTOMATIC STACK**

- SharePoint 2013 Online Plan 2
- Windows 7 SP1, 64-bit IE 9.0.18 (KB2846071), 32-bit
- Office Standard 2010 (14.0.6029.1000)
- Also installed:

  - Project Professional 2010 (14.0.6029.1000)
  - Visio Premium (14.0.6029.1000)
  - SharePoint Designer 2013 (15.0.4517.1005)

**THE PROBABLE PROBLEM**

I was already installing SharePoint Designer 2013 when I first tried to open one of the Excel file in the 2010 desktop client. I had already edited the file in the 2013 desktop client of another computer with no problems and wasn't aware that the process differing with the differing client version. I was prompted to allow my Office 2010 installation be prepared to handle the file. Since I didn't want two installation / configuration processes running on the (possibly) the same tool suite simultaneously in case of conflict, I declined. I assumed I would be prompted again, but I have not.

**WHAT I'VE ALREADY TRIED**

- I've tried other browsers on the same Win7 machine.
- I've had successful results on other machines with the same OS, browser, and Office Standard 2010, on the same network. Thus, it's not a firewall or other network issue.
- I've cleared caches and deleted cookies said browsers.
- I've deleted the contents of this folder: C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\14.0\OfficeFileCache
- I've configured SP to force opening docs in desktop client, hoping that would trigger a config reset. My results did not change and the config change has been reverted.
- Per the advice at http://blogs.technet.com/b/raymond_ris/archive/2013/04/04/cannot-open-or-create-word-documents-in-sharepoint-2013-with-office-2010-and-project-2013.aspx, I've disabled Office 2010's SharePoint Foundation Support then run Repair on Office 2010. After the repair, Office 2010's SharePoint Foundation Support was enabled. Results have not changed.
- I've opened Office templates directly from the Office website, confirming that, at least in some cases, I can open Office documents from IE9. (Success seemed haphazard.)

**UPDATE**

I've now uninstalled SharePoint Designer 2013 and my attempt to open the Word doc results in the following message: "Sorry, but to open this document, your computer must be running a supported version of Microsoft Word and a browser that supports opening files directly from Office Web Apps."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SharePoint Designer 2013 uninstalled, I repeated the aforementioned process of disabling Office 2010's SharePoint Foundation Support and then running Repair on Office 2010. After the repair, SP-created/stored Word and Excel documents are opening smoothly in 2010 desktop clients from IE9.

So, it would appear that the problem for Office 2010 is having SharePoint Designer 2013 uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Situation (two clients and SharePoint Server 2013)
Client 1:

- Win7 x64.
- Office 2010.
- Lync 2010.
- Visio 2010.

Client 2:

- Same as Client 1 but added SharePoint Desinger 2013.

Problem:

Client 2 not able to open any Visio file by directly clicking a link to open file fron SPS2013. Dont know about Word, Excel and Adobe Reader becouse we use the Web-Apps and that works fine.

Client 1 no problems.

Work around for Client 2:

Right click the link of the Visio file and select either "Open", "Open in new Tab" or "Open in new windows", and a popup will show to either "Open", "Save" or "Save As".